# How to enable impress presenter-console?

Tags: 15.04, multiple-monitors, libreoffice, console

I am trying to get the presenter-console working on my Ubuntu 15.04 Notebook. There is an external Display hooked up to it via VGA in extended mode:

[image]

Here are my slide-show settings in Impress:

[image]

When I start the presentation, the presenter-console does not show up.

I tried rearranging the displays, so the external monitor is on the right. Also, I tried this [OpenOffice add-on](http://extensions.openoffice.org/de/project/oracle-presenter-console).

However, none of these methods worked.

Do you know how I can enable the presenter-console?

-Josef

Answer (score 0):

The presenter-console can be enabled in

tools -> options -> LibreOffice Impress -> general -> Enable Presenter Console